# Blazor HttpClient stuck in GetAsync

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

I'm making test in a Client Side Blazor app targeting  Blazor 3.0.0-preview4-19216-03

The razor page:

```
@page "/counter"
@using BlazorServiceTest
@inject IWebCrawlServiceAsync WebCrawler

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @debug</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@functions {
    string debug = "";

    async void IncrementCount()
    {
        debug = await WebCrawler.GetWeb();
    }
}
```

The dependency injection:

```
using BlazorServiceTest;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace BlazorServicesTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {   
            services.AddSingleton<IWebCrawlServiceAsync, WebCrawlServiceAsync>();            
        }

        public void Configure(IComponentsApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.AddComponent<App>("app");
        }
    }
}
```

The Service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlazorServiceTest
{
    public interface IWebCrawlServiceAsync
    {
        Task<string> GetWeb();
    }

    public class WebCrawlServiceAsync : IWebCrawlServiceAsync
    {
        private HttpClient _client;    

        public WebCrawlServiceAsync(HttpClient client)
        {
            _client = client;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetWeb()
        {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://postman-echo.com/response-headers?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2");
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I click in Increment count nothing happens and the service call to `GetWeb` it's stuck in the `GetAsync` call.

UPDATE

If I debug the service WebCrawler in Chrome's WASM debugger, he request is being made

[image]

But the response section is empty:

[image]

Comment: Where are you adding `HttpClient`? Or is that added automatically?

Comment: It's injected by Blazor and tweaked so it work in a WASM enviroment. I created a new instance of HttpClient by myself and didn't work either.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the `async void`. I am reading up more to be sure/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a client-side app you can only acces your own origin or sites that support CORS.

In order to verify that this is your issue, you can try  `https://postman-echo.com/response-headers?foo1=bar1&access-control-allow-origin=*`, that might work.

But it will only work for that site. You normally have no control over the response headers. It's not a fix.

So, Blazor client-side is just not a good platform for a webcrawler.
The same goes for any app on JS or WASM.

Blazor server-side should have no problems. Or use a Web API service.

---

You can try this in a Wasm app:

```
@page "/"
@inject HttpClient Http

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GetData1">With CORS</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="GetData2">No CORS</button>
</div>
<div>@json</div>

@code
{
    string json = ".";

    async Task GetData1()
    {        
        json = await Http.GetStringAsync(
         "https://postman-echo.com/response-headers" + 
         "?foo1=bar1&access-control-allow-origin=*");
    }

    async Task GetData2()
    {
        json = "Getting w/o CORS... ";
        json = await Http.GetStringAsync(
          "https://postman-echo.com/response-headers?foo1=bar1");
    }
}
```

Comment: It was a CORS issue, using that URL with 'access-control-allow-origin=*' did the work. Gonna test Blazor Serverside as it looks more robuts. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Oh, yes, how did it do the work? Please, enlighten us. 'access-control-allow-origin=*' in the url above is nothing but a query string parameter, which can be echoed back like the two other parameters. Just place this url in your browser's address bar and hit enter to see the returned json. You can easily replace the last parameter with this: 'allow-origin=*'

Comment: Incidentally, you certainly should learn and test server-side Blazor, but it has got nothing to do with the issue. As I've already said, the problen is not with Blazor or HttpClient.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, what is this: 'access-control-allow-origin=*' What are you trying to do here ;) "access-control-allow-origin" is a Response header provided by the server

Comment: @Issac, look at the URL and read the docs there. This is a special site for testing APIs.

Comment: So ? Could you please tell me what do you get by placing 'access-control-allow-origin=*' in the url... You write: "In order to verify, you can try....." What does the addition of another parameter can do. There were two parameters: foo1 and foo2; now you introduce (or change ) a new parameter; that is all. Do you realize that 'access-control-allow-origin' ?

Comment: You still haven't read the docs on https://postman-echo.com. Did you at least notice the /response-headers part of the URL ?

Comment: OK, @Henk Holterman. I'll answer you, and I expect you to answer me back. No I haven't read it. Why should I read it. Yes, I did notice  "the /response-headers part of the URL", so what. I also noticed that your answers are short and, sorry to say evasive. Now, can you answer the question from above:  Could you please tell me what do you get by placing 'access-control-allow-origin=*' in the url... You write: "In order to verify, you can try....." What does the addition of another parameter can do.

Comment: As testified by etragu, "did the work". Why don't you just try it?  The post is an mcve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192814/discussion-between-issac-and-henk-holterman).

Comment: No, I don't do chat. And the discussion is closed as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it has something to do with the `async void`.

You need to have the handler return a `Task`, not `void`

For example

```
@page "/counter"
@using BlazorServiceTest
@inject IWebCrawlServiceAsync WebCrawler

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @debug</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="@IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@functions {
    string debug { get; set; } = "";

    async Task IncrementCount() { //<-- Note Change here
        debug = await WebCrawler.GetWeb();
    }
}
```

support for async event handler is available in the framework

Reference [GitHub Issue: Calling an async function via onclick](https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/163)

Comment: Hi Nkosi, thanks for the answer but unfortunately it didn't work, I added the "private async Task IncrementCount()" but no difference.

Comment: @Nkosi, you may use async void with events. I'm not sure the this.StateHasChanged(); call is necessary, as this method is always automatically called after an event is raised.

Comment: Blazor supports `async Task` for events, very much preferable. When you do use `async void` then also end with a StateHasChanged() because the framework won't (can't) do that.

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to a CORS configuration issue on the server of which you have no control. I believe that this issue has nothing to do with Blazor. To verify this, define a local json file in your app and access it with the same code you use in your application.

Hope this works...

**UPDATE**

I'm not entirely sure that the request fails due to CORS configuration issue, at least not exclusively. It seems to me that it is also related to SSL/TLS. 
This error message was issued by Fiddler:

> fiddler.network.https> HTTPS handshake to failed.
>   System.IO.IOException Unable to read data  from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
>   host.  < An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

The underlying connection is closed and no trust relationship can be established for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

I guess I'll post this question in github to get a better understanding of what went wrong here.

Comment: "It's injected by Blazor and tweaked so it work in a WASM enviroment", said by @etragu . Sorry, no difference... I did not notice the code before...