# How to get title of web page using Blazor?

Tags: c#, cors, webclient, blazor, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to make aplication in Blazor and when I try to get title of any web page, I recieve error **System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.** Is there any other solution than this? I also started with HttpClient but don't have idea how to do it and using this get error with CORS authorization.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Regex reg = new Regex("<title>(.*)</title>");
        MatchCollection m = reg.Matches(str);
        if (m.Count > 0)
        {
            return m[0].Value.Replace("<title>", "").Replace("</title>", "");
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
```

Comment: Related, but not an exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953929

Answer (score 2):

With Blazor Server-side your code should work, albeit HttpClient would be better.

But PlatformNotSupportedException means you are running this on Blazor WebAssembly. There you have to use HttpClient, but

> ... with HttpClient [...] get error with CORS authorization.

And that problem won't go away, no matter what you use.

Blazor WebAssembly is limited by the standard 'sandbox' security rules that hold for any JavaScript or WebAssembly application.

You will not be able to access sites at random. API sites may allow this using a CORS header but websites outside your own domain will not be accessible.