# When sending GET request to local API on ASP.NET 5 (Core) I get the following message Unable to read data from the transport connection:

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

So i have tried to consume an API i have made locally and i receive this error message while attempting to request data from an endpoint

Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was closed

now I thought I could fix it when enabling CORS policy but I dont know if the problem might be somewhere else

here is the code, here throws an exception after GetAsync

````cs
httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                var url = Url("api/Employees");
                 var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                 responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                if(responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)



                ```
on startup.cs for the web api
on configure services method

```services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder => builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44309"));
            });```
in configure method ```

            app.UseCors();```
in the controller
````

````
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors]
public class EmployeeController:ControllerBase```
````

so what could I be doing possibly wrong?

stack trace

at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.d__56.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithRetryAsync>d__72.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__5.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsyncCore>d__85.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at BlazorApp.Services.EmployeeServices.d__7.MoveNext() in C:\Users\User\Documents\repos\BlazorApp\BlazorApp\Services\EmployeeServices.cs:line 61

Comment: What is the full url?

Comment: @Serge https://localhost:44365/api/Employees

Answer (score 0):

try  this code

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var baseAddress = "http://localhost:44365;
    var api = "/api/Employees";
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
    var response = await client.GetAsync(api)
      //var statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
    var stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(stringData);
    }
}
```

remove [EnableCors] from  the action and be sure that localhost:44365 is running on the local IIS

Comment: I tried your solution and throws the same exception  Unable to read data from the transport connection: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto..¨¨ I will add the stack trace to the OP

Comment: @PontiacGTX Did you try to type in the browser " localhost:44365/api/Employees " and what is  result?

Comment: it returns a json but when I use the same request on a http client it throws the exception with the above stack trace

Comment: @PontiacGTX and what code is on EmployeeServices.cs:line 61

Comment: var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(api);

Comment: @PontiacGTX And did you check the developer tools of your browser too?

Comment: I think I didnt receive any error on blazor it keeps awaiting and loads only the screen to load the data the only message from blazor is [2021-09-19T20:21:58.418Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:44309/_blazor?id=fVuepdXIl8muBomwhcM6_A.

Comment: @PontiacGTX I mean Chrome or Edge has a developer tools in menu

Comment: the problem is at the backend because i have setup a breakpoint and it breaks when it calls GetAsync method....  I wonder if somehow there should be a special package for blazor? I dont know really I am using a server side Blazor project

Comment: a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953929/blazor-httpclient-stuck-in-getasync

Comment: Well I didnt realize the uri was using http rather https that was the issuse I should have double checked the string, I am so sorry for taking your time